# Can we change slide animation direction?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode, ios-4.2

In my app there is a main table view. When a cell is clicked, a DetailView is created which shows details of that cell's item. On every DetailView i have next and previous buttons which helps users to go to next and previous item's DetailView without going back to RootView. When i click next button. animation is from right to left. and its same when i click previous button. Animation should be from left to right when i click previous button. Is there anyways to change that animation direction. I don't wanna use [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES], because i have alot of items and its hard to take care of navigation stack. So is there any way i can change right to left animation to left to right when i click previous button.

Comment: You'd probably want to use an up and down arrow just like the Mail navigation bar.

Comment: How you navigate between detail views; by using navigationController as pushViewController or some other other logic? as you don't like for popViewControllerAnimated.

Comment: yeah i am using navigationController.

Comment: problem solved. i used popViewControllerAnimated. and now i like it :). thanx for help. take care

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be implemented a navigation controller and push and pop, and you don't have to deal with a messy navigation stack because what you have to do is just 1) push a view and remove the previous view from the stack (in 'next' case), or 2) insert a view into the stack in front of the current view and pop the current view (in 'previous' case).

So far, however, I see no reason to use a navigation controller here. When you are switching to a new detail view, prepare the new view as hidden and insert the view on top of the view layers. Then, create a CATransition object with desired options, unhide the new view, and deal with the previous detail view (like, remove it). For example,

```
CATransition transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = 0.75;
transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
transition.subtype = (nextDidPressed)? kCATransitionFromRight : kCATransitionFromLeft;
newDetailView.hidden = NO;
detailView.hidden = YES;
self.detailView = newDetailView;
```

The above code makes a few assumptions on your view layouts and declared properties. Make changes according to the other part of your code appropriately.

Comment: See ViewTransitions sample project for details.

Comment: well i took ur first advise. it was really easy. and thats cool that we dont have to worry about navigation stack. well i m quite new in this. but got it. thanx for ur help bro. take care